# Suggestions for a GUI configured proxy server for Windows

Tags: proxy, web

I think what I am after is a proxy server ...

I have some web applications written in Python for a small scale deployment on a Windows machine. I was envisaging each web app running its paster instance on a different port and a front end proxy server redirecting ordinary requests to say `host.com/app1` to `host.com:5000` and `host.com/app2` to `host.com:5001`

I need it to be pretty simple configuration, preferably through a GUI or webinterface since it will be left in the hands of not so techie types.

Answer (score 1):

[Nginx](http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766288369/using-nginx-reverse-proxy),  [haproxy](http://steven.4bits.eu/2010/07/using-haproxy-as-reverse-proxy.html), and [squid](http://www.visolve.com/squid/whitepapers/reverseproxy.php) are probably the most commonly used for running reverse proxies, but all of them focus on caching and/or include at least a minimal HTTP server.  Since it sounds like you need neither of these things, but rather just something to forward requests to the right host/port running IIS, you could look at [pound reverse proxy](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/). It should do what you're looking for and although it can be installed on just about anything *but* Windows, it's not difficult to configure on an old "beige box" at or behind your WAN gateway that should keep the complexity to a minimum.  No gui, but there is a live CD of Pound based on FreeBSD out there that's easy to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried specifically what you're asking, but I would probably start by looking at Apache and `mod_rewrite`.

Of course, Apache is not one for 'simple configuration', but there are some GUI managers out there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite what you want, but it does explain why it's not as simple as it looks at first glance: http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx